# no puedo instalar bootstrap con el npm install bootstrap --save en ubuntu

Tags: bootstrap-4, npm, packages

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /mnt/c/users/fejua/documents/proyecto_guia/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0 while parsing near 'const package = `{
npm ERR! JSON.parse  ...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jhon0121/.npm/_logs/2020-07-20T02_37_31_611Z-debug.log
```

este es el mensaje que me deja agradezco quien pueda sacarme de esta duda, ya reinstale el npm el nodejs

Comment: Puedes compartir el contenido del archivo `proyecto_guia/package.json`? debe tener algun error de sintaxis como dice en el mensaje

Comment: {
  "name": "proyecto_guia",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "nuestro primer proyecto de nodejs",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server"
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/jhon0121/guias_hoteles/src/master/"
  },
  "author": "jhon esteban",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  }
}